Unable to save or refresh reports
I have my initial set up of civiCRM on C-panel (vs 122), civiCRM 5.79.0-wordpress (6.7.1) PHP vs 8.3.13. I have set up membership and donation forms and tested these with a few entries - which I can see under the Contributions Dashboard. Emails were sucessfully sent to each signee. (Cron appears to be working and manual execution of Scheduled Jobs (Fetch bounces, fetch-activities and process_mailing are apparently successful) mailings>mailing reports>mailing details>refresh results sends me to a 403 (forbidden) page not found. I get the same response with all the reports (e.g. membership, contributions...). BTW I dont have this problem with my local version of the same website on my PC. Any suggested fixes wuld be appreciated!

Ok. After going down many rabbit holes of no return, I have discovered the problem was the security rules on my C-Panel ModSecurity. Problem now resolved. The offending Rule was turned off.

Thanks for answering your own question. Are you able to say which rule was the issue? This might be helpful to others in the same situation.
